# Retain precision during numeric sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, dictionary, numbers

I'm using this function to sort an array of number, some of which are decimals. But in the sort I'm losing the `.0` on those values. I'd like to retain this precision when it's specified, but not add it when it isn't.

**For example:** `[1.5, 2, 0.75, 1.0, 0.75]` should sort to `[2, 1.5, 1.0, 0.75]` but using the function below it sorts to `[2, 1.5, 1, 0.75]`

```
var sortNums = function( arr ) {
        // Quit if arr is not an array.
        if ( !$.isArray(arr) ) { return false; }

        // Sort highest to lowest:
        arr.sort(function(a,b) {return (b-a);}); 

        // Remove non-numeric vals and return:
        return $.map(arr, function(v) {if (typeof v === 'number') {return v;}}); 
};
```

Comment: Did you know that `1.0` and `1` are the same number to computers?

Comment: @minitech Of course! ;) But I still need to do this b/c I'm sending them to a string later that expects the original values.

Comment: So you need to use an array of strings, not an array of numbers, because they're not in any format to begin with. `1 === 01 === 0x1 === 1.0` (And therefore the `typeof` check needs to be removed.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JavaScript removes tailing decimal zeros.

```
var x = 1.0;
x; // 1
```

If you want to keep the decimals you need to cast them as strings. And you could then cast them as numbers in the sort process, if needed.

Comment: Also, if you made your array and outputted it before sorting, it would still remove the `.0`

Comment: Thx / got it. They'd have to be strings to begin with. I was trying to use one array for two purposes—one needing nums and one needing strings.

Answer (score 1):

They don't have any sort of precision to begin with, per se. But `sort` already works properly and with JavaScript's infinitely useful automatic conversions, `-` does the work for you. See: http://jsfiddle.net/hqc33/